# Eclipse - Gradle - Android SDK (failed to target android-22: ....)

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, sdk

I'm having a problem when I try to import a Gradle project in Eclipse.
It shows me the error

```
failed to find target android-22: /Users/..../Documents/Development"
```

I'm using Eclipse on Mac OS X and yes I have the android-22 sdk installed.
While trying to resolve the problem I've tried installing everything I can from the Android SDK Manager, but still nothing was done.

Comment: Have you tried a clean build and restarting eclipse. I find it can be a bit buggy in this area, also check the manifest that the target is set correctly, try setting to 21 to check if it allows it

Comment: Can you please guide me step by step?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not have the Android-22 sdk installed. Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and check to see if Android 5.1 (API 22) is installed.

Answer (score 0):

ok first do a complete clean build of your project Project->Clean... if that doesnt work close eclipse and reopen. Check the manifest, locate the manifest in your project and have a look at the xml it should have something like this

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

if this is missing add it, if it is there then change from 22 to 21 , clean build andf run. You may have references to target 22 but not actually telling the project to use it. I hope this helps